# Как сделать так, чтобы пользователю открывался следующий экран при заполнении формы, в зависимости от выбранного ранее варианта?

Tags: ui, forms

Необходимо сделать приложение заказа еды, в котором Пользователь (User - devise), делая Заказ (Order), сначала выбирает заведение, а затем его перенаправляет в меню этого заведения (меню в самом приложении).

Могу предположить, что тут нужны nested forms (очень плохо разбираюсь) или Ajax/JavaScript (вообще не разбираюсь) для смены экранов.

Как реализовать такую функцию (если не сложно, то максимально подробно)? Может быть, существует какой-то не сложный гем?

Пример экрана выбора заведения, который сменяется экраном с меню выбранного заведения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если речь о приложении, то при чём тут вообще вложенные формы и AJAX? Там же не браузерная среда.

Comment: Вообще да, меню конкретного надо через ajax подгружать.

Comment: Ну я думаю через phonegap портировать в конечном итоге. То что подлагивать будет - не беда.

Comment: В остальном спасибо, сегодня чисто случайно нашел решение которое может подойти - в foundation 6 есть drilldown menu. Функционал схож с необходимым (хотя и не полностью в части заполнения rails формы - но как временное решение сойдет), если не обнаружится нюансов - буду его использовать.